# Default StringComparer used by Dictionary<string, T>

Tags: c#, dictionary, string-comparison

I'm used to specifying a `StringComparer` whenever creating a `Dictionary` keyed by `string` and I'm wondering what comparer gets used if none is specified. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor) say

> This constructor uses the default generic equality comparer, EqualityComparer.Default

Debugging revealed the run-time type of `System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer<string>` but I couldn't find any documentation on it.

What does it do? Does it match any of the pre-defined `StringComparer`s like Ordinal or CurrentCulture?

Comment: Here is the source for it https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,e59de2b23f38e633

Comment: It calls `string.Equals(string)` and `string.GetHashCode()`

Comment: *"What does it do"* - perhaps too broad question. What problem are you solving?

Comment: But "What does it do" I meant "What semantics does it implement" like Ordinal or OrdinalIgnoreCase.

Comment: The documentation for string.Equals is explicit about the type of comparison it does.  See the remarks section.

Comment: Seeing a concrete implementation is nice but does not guarantee that my implementation does the same. I'd rather see some documentation that states something like "Dictionary<string. T>" uses an Ordinal comparer."

Comment: @SergeySlepov So since you want to see what the documentation says on the subject, when you went and read the documentation, how were you unsatisfied by what it says?

Comment: From the docs on `EqualityComparer`: "The `Default` property checks whether type `T` implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` interface and, if so, returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses that implementation." From the docs on `string.Equals(string)` (which implements `IEquatable<string>`): "This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison." Documenting the behavior individually for every type of key you could use in a `Dictionary` would be, well, impractical to say the least.

Comment: @Servy @JeroenMostert I can't find any documentation that confirms that `String`'s implementation of IEquatable calls `string.Equals(string)`.

Comment: Oh, so the absence of IEquatable.Equals in String's "Explicit Interface Implementations" implies that it's implemented by string.Equals. OK, that does it for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is documented, if only by omission. The list of [explicit interface implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string#explicit-interface-implementations) confirms that `IEquatable<string>` is *not* explicitly implemented, therefore `string.Equals(string)` must implement `IEquatable<string>.Equals(string)`. Elementary, dear Watson!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is **Ordinal** but proving that took some digging around.

Firstly, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-ctor) for Dictionary's default constructor say:

> Initializes a new instance of the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> class that [...] uses the **default equality comparer** for the key type.

EqualityComparer.Default docs [say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

Since System.String does [not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0#explicit-interface-implementations) implement System.IEquatable, Default should use its Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode which [perform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-6.0#system-string-equals(system-object)) the Ordinal comparison:

> **Remarks**
>
> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.

Comment: Comments are transient; the answer should still make sense if they all got deleted. If you want to have this up as an answer, take some time to include the relevant information.

Comment: ...but `System.String` **does** implement `IEquatable<String>` in `public Boolean String.Equals(String? other)` - though (as of .NET 7, at least), that `String.Equals` method provides its own ordinal comparer (in `String.EqualsHelper`) instead of using `StringComparer`.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware if moving from .NET Framework to .NET 5+ that there are some non obvious changes to [the way strings work in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus) that go beyond the default StringComparer.

This caught me with string ordering where something as simple as this can give different results (both on Windows):

#### Code

```
new[] { "123-CAT", "123CAT" }.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

#### .NET Framework

```
[ "123CAT", "123-CAT" ]
```

#### .NET 7 (or .NET 5 and above)

```
[ "123-CAT", "123CAT" ]
```

This is an excerpt from my question where I came across [an unexpected sorting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344143/unable-to-reproduce-net-framework-string-sort-order-in-net-7-even-when-setting/75344378#75344378).