# Unable to reproduce .NET Framework string sort order in .NET 7 even when setting culture explicitly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have some legacy code running on .NET Framework 4.8 which sorts some product codes and puts the result in a single database column. This has been running for years accumulating data I can't easily modify. I need it to work the same on .NET 7.

The code is simple:

#### Code

```
new[] { "123-CAT", "123CAT" }.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

#### .NET Framework

```
[ "123CAT", "123-CAT" ]
```

#### .NET 7

```
[ "123-CAT", "123CAT" ]
```

I need the .NET 7 code to match the .NET Framework result.

So I played around with different cultures thinking it would be simple. To my surprise I could not find any `StringComparer` culture in .NET 7 that would give the result `["123CAT", "123-CAT"]`.

These are all the versions I tried. The values marked with `***` are the result I want.

```
// .NET Framework: 123CAT, 123-CAT   ***
// .NET 7        : 123-CAT, 123CAT
var list_default = new[] { "123-CAT", "123CAT" }.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

// .NET Framework: 123CAT, 123-CAT   ***
// .NET 7        : 123-CAT, 123CAT
var list_currentCulture = new[] { "123-CAT", "123CAT" }.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.CurrentCulture).ToArray();

// .NET Framework: 123CAT, 123-CAT   ***
// .NET 7        : 123-CAT, 123CAT
var list_invariant = new[] { "123-CAT", "123CAT" }.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.InvariantCulture).ToArray();

// .NET Framework: 123-CAT, 123CAT
// .NET 7        : 123-CAT, 123CAT
var list_ordinal = new[] { "123-CAT", "123CAT" }.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToArray();
```

Based on ASCII table I would *expect* and probably want the `123-CAT` to come first (since the - is an ASCII 45 character) and .NET 7 is doing exactly that. But I need it to match the .NET Framework behavior.

I can get .NET Framework to match .NET 7 (using `StringComparer.Ordinal`) but not the other way around!

Comment: Try adding `<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>` to csproj

Comment: See [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu)

Comment: @shingo. US-en on Windows 11. And the code is normally running on Windows Server 2018.

Comment: @GuruStron That did it :-) I found all the culture stuff but didn't think to search for Globalization. If you want to add that as an answer I can accept it. And now I can sleep better :-) And hope this doesn't have any other impact!

Comment: Although ironically, I'm considering switching to a Mac for some development so it may end up being easier to switch the legacy code to use `Ordinal` and just batch update everything. But this will work great for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET 5 on Windows was breaking change which switched globalization to ICU from NLS. To revert to NLS on Windows you can add next xml switch to .cpproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Read more:

- [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu)
- [Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus)

Comment: Hidden in that page is this very useful article about string comparison changes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus

Comment: I decided in the end to bite the bullet and change both to OrdinalIgnoreCase and go back and clean the database. I only have 12,104 unique combinations over 1.1 million rows. So here goes... and thanks again for your quick reply.

Comment: @SergeySlepov I would argue that this was a quite necessary measure cause otherwise you would have different behaviour on different platforms.